# Is there a way to get the checkbox state from .html()

Tags: jquery, pushstate, html5-history

I am trying to use `history.pushState` with an ajax search but it is not saving checkbox state.

This is an example of how I am saving the form to the pushstate:

```
history.pushState({ FilterSearch: container.html() }, 'search', formAction);
```

Where `container` is the form with checkboxes and results and `formAction` is the url.  This is called onchange of the checkbox (in the result of the ajax call).

I feel the problem is that `.html` doesn't seem to get the updated status of the checkbox - see the snippet below.

```js
$('#test1').on('change', function() {
 console.log($('#test').html());
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="test">
  <input type="checkbox" id="test1" value="test">
</div>
```

If you look at the console as you check and uncheck the input, you can see it never has the `checked` attribute added to it.

Is there anyway to get the pushstate to remember the status of the checkboxes?

Comment: The staus of checkboxes (or other object) is kept in the DOM tree not in the HTML code.

Comment: isn't `$('#test').html()` calling an object in the DOM?

Comment: @Pete then you have to apply the attribute to it explicitly, i guess.

Comment: It's getting the content not the state. This is why there's a difference between the result of  `attr` and `prop` functions in jQuery.

Comment: @Pete  here i am agreed with _ADreNaLiNe-DJ_. There are differences between `.attr()` and `.prop()`, where `.prop()` doesn't add new state in the DOM but not visible, on the other side `.attr()` adds the attribute to the element in the dom.

Comment: @ADreNaLiNe-DJ and @Jai, damn! I guess I'll have to loop through the current checked boxes and apply the attribute to the `container.html()`

Comment: @Pete Why do you need the state in the HTML ?

Comment: @ADreNaLiNe-DJ so that I can use the back button and it remembers the ajax search history rather than just going to the previous url before any of the searches were performed - I push the form html and search results into the history so the back button will recall them

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to the comments from ADreNaLiNe-DJ and Jai for pointing me in the right direction.  I was able to set the attribute and then call `.html` as follows:

```js
$('#test1').on('change', function() {
    if (this.checked) {
        $(this).attr('checked', true);
    } else {
        $(this).removeAttr('checked');
    }
    console.log($('#test').html());
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="test">
  <input type="checkbox" id="test1" value="test">
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can check if a checkbox is checked or not by using `.is(':checked')`, it returns true or false

```js
$('#test1').on('change', function() {
 console.log($('#test1').is(':checked'));
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="test">
  <input type="checkbox" id="test1" value="test">
</div>
```

Comment: This doesn't answer the question.

Comment: Unfortunately I cannot use this as I am pushing the html into the pushstate so I need to use `.html`